# JavaScript: how to change form action attribute value based on selection?

Tags: jquery, forms, dynamic, action

I'm trying to change the form action based on the selected value from a dropdown menu.

Basically, the HTML looks like this:

```
<form class="search-form" id="search-form" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/search/user">
<select id="selectsearch" class="form-select" name="selectsearch">
<option value="people">Search people</option>
<option value="node">Search content</option>
</select>

<label>Enter your keywords: </label>
 <input type="text" class="form-text" value="" size="40" id="edit-keys" name="keys" maxlength="255" />

<input type="submit" class="form-submit" value="Search" id="edit-submit" name="search"/>
</form>
```

If "people" is selected, (which it is by default), the action should be "/search/user", and if content is selected, the action should be "/search/content"

I'm still searching around, but haven't been able to find out how to do this.

Answer (score 277, accepted):

```
$("#selectsearch").change(function() {
  var action = $(this).val() == "people" ? "user" : "content";
  $("#search-form").attr("action", "/search/" + action);
});
```

Comment: That is way better than what I was trying... Thank you

Comment: Worked perfect. Thanks. I updated this code to change the action on submit instead of on form change.

Comment: If you design for mobile devices it would be better to change action "on submit" for performance issues. Check my answer below.

Comment: Use `prop` instead of `attr`. Example = `$("#search-form").prop ("action", "/search/" + action); `

Answer (score 24):

If you only want to change form's action, I prefer changing action on-form-submit, rather than on-input-change. It fires only once.

```
$('#search-form').submit(function(){
  var formAction = $("#selectsearch").val() == "people" ? "user" : "content";
  $("#search-form").attr("action", "/search/" + formAction);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple and easy in javascipt

```
<script>

  document.getElementById("selectsearch").addEventListener("change", function(){

  var get_form =   document.getElementById("search-form") // get form 
  get_form.action =  '/search/' +  this.value; // assign value 

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use

```
$('#search-form').setAttribute('action', '/controllerName/actionName');
```

rather than

```
$('#search-form').attr('action', '/controllerName/actionName');
```

So, based on trante's answer we have:

```
$('#search-form').submit(function() {
    var formAction = $("#selectsearch").val() == "people" ? "user" : "content";
    $("#search-form").setAttribute("action", "/search/" + formAction);
});
```

Using `setAttribute` can save you a lot of time potentially.

Comment: why would DOMElement `setAttribute` save any time over using jquery `attr`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change from Pure javascript means use follow methods. Same as [Ankush Kumar's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60055152/7177214) code with Extra methods

```js
function fn_one(){
  document.formname.action="https://google.com/search?q=form+submit+using+name";
}
function fn_two(){
  document.getElementsByName("formname")[0].action="https://google.com/search?q=form+submit+using+name+method+2";
}
function fn_three(){
  document.getElementById("formid").action="https://google.com/search?q=form+submit+using+ID";
}
```

```html
<form name="formname" id="formid" action="google.com/search?q=" target="_blank">
  <div>
    <button type="button" onclick="fn_one()">Change By Name {1}</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="fn_two()">Change By Name {2}</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="fn_three()">Change By ID</button>
  </div>
   <div>
    <button type="submit">Go To Google</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score -16):

Is required that you have a form?
If not, then you could use this:

```html
<div>
    <input type="hidden" value="ServletParameter" />
    <input type="button" id="callJavaScriptServlet" onclick="callJavaScriptServlet()" />
</div>
```

with the following JavaScript:

```js
function callJavaScriptServlet() {
    this.form.action = "MyServlet";
    this.form.submit();
}
```

Comment: this.form.submit(); will have no sense since there are actually no forms an thus - nothing to submit