# Submit a different form depending on character count in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, forms, input, character

Ok, so here's what I want to do, preferably with jQuery 1.4.2:

- Have one `<input type="text">` and one `<input type="button">`
- If the `text-input` has exactly *N number characters*, I want a click on the `button` to submit the form with one action.
- Else, the button submits the form with another action.

Unfortunately I'm a jQuery n00b, and I can't get it to work… ._.

Comment: What do you mean by "action"? The `action` tag of the `form` element?

Comment: Yes, sorry, should've clarified that. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a `<button type="submit">`, you could handle the form's `submit` event and change the action accordingly, so that the submit directs to the page you want.  This should be the easiest way, with minimal code necessary -- something like:

```
var myForm = $('#myForm');
myForm.submit(function ()
{
    if ($('#myInput').val().length == 42)
        myForm.attr('action', 'http://somewhere.com');
    else
        myForm.attr('action', 'http://somewhereelse.com');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of characters, do `$('input[type=text]').val().length`

Answer (score 0):

[**This**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925614/jquery-change-form-action-based-on-selection) questions chosen answer should help. Place that code (once you have adapted) below:

```
$("myFormID").submit( function () {

//Put adapted code here

} )
```

;

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
        $('#button').click(function() {
            var textLength = $('#text').val();

            if (textLength.length === 10) // 10 for exmaple
            {
                //do bla
            }
            else { 
                // do labla
            }
        });
    });
```