# Change form action based on multiple <select> options using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, forms

What I'm trying to do is to change the form action based on selected options from multiple selections. In this case, two selections but same idea. I'm trying to direct the user to a specific url on submit. So far, it does direct the user but it only returns a "female" with whatever "age" options are selected. The age part is correct but it won't differentiate between "male" or "female" options. So I get a url in return like: http: //domain.com/somepage.php#female_(age selection)

I'm a noob with javascript but Ive been trying for hours to make this work and still trying. I did get some help from: [javascript - change form action based on selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925614/jquery-change-form-action-based-on-selection?answertab=votes#tab-top) but still unsolved. Any help is much appreciated!

markup:

```
<form action="">
    <fieldset>
        <select id="gender">
            <option value="male">male</option>
            <option value="female">female</option>
        </select>
        <select id="age">
            <option value="teen">teen</option>
            <option value="adult">adult</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#gender").change(function() {
    var action = $(this).val() == "male";
        $("#age").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "teen"){
        $("form").attr("action", "somepage.php#male_teen")};
    if ($(this).val() == "adult"){
        $("form").attr("action", "somepage.php#male-adult")};
    });
    var action = $(this).val() == "female";
        $("#age").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "teen"){
        $("form").attr("action", "somepage.php#female-teen")};
    if ($(this).val() == "adult"){
        $("form").attr("action", "somepage.php#female-adult")};
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested, but something like this maybe:

```
$("#gender, #age").on('change', function() {
    var gender = $("#gender").val(),
        age = $("#age").val(),
        site = "somepage.php#"+gender+"-"+age; //inconsistent use of -/_

        $("form").attr("action", site)};
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign an id to your form and then

```
$('#formid').submit(function(){
  var gender = $("#gender").val();
  var age = $("#age").val();
  $("#formid").attr('action','somepage.php#'+gender+'-'+age);
});
```

or even better

```
$('#formid').submit(function(){
  var gender = $("#gender").val();
  var age = $("#age").val();
  $("#formid").attr('action','somepage.php#'+gender+'-'+age);
  if(gender == '' or age == ''){
    alert('Please select a gender and age');
    return false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work for you...

```
$("#age, #gender").change(function() {
    switch();
});

function switch(){

   // Build out this function with the rest of the logic
   // that you are checking for

   if($(form #age).val=='teen' && $(form #gender).val=='male'){
      $("form").attr("action", "somepage.php#male-teen")
   }
}
```