# How to set action value in form depending on the value of select?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to set action value in form depending on the value of select?

```
<form action="/my-url/{{design.id}}" method="get">
    <select name="producttype">
       <option value="lite">Select one of option</option>
       <option value="a">Option a</option>
       <option value="b">Option b</option>
       <option value="c">Option c</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

How to create something like this:

If select option have value `a` my form action will be: `<form action="/my-url/{{design.id}}/a" method="get">`

If select option have value `b` my form action will be: `<form action="/my-url/{{design.id}}/b" method="get">`

Comment: Why don't you simply pass in the value of `producctype` as an URL parameter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925614/jquery-change-form-action-based-on-selection

Comment: Instead of JavaScript you should consider rewriting your server-side script so that it accepts the url `/my-url/{{design.id}}?producttype=a` instead, possibly redirecting to `/my-url/{{design.id}}/a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work:

```
$("select[name='producttype']").change(function(){
    var form = $("form");
    var action = "/my-url/{{design.id}}/" + $(this).val();
    form.attr("action", action);
});
```

Couple of things to note:

1. If you have multiple forms on the page, then you need a more accurate way of selecting the correct form - perhaps an `id` attribute
2. What is `{{design.id}}`? Is this meant to be generated dynamically?

---

A solution to Note 2 could be to include the base URL as a `data-*` attribute, something like this:

```
<form action="/my-url/{{design.id}}" data-baseurl="/my-url/{{design.id}}/" method="get">
```

and then change the above javascript to be like this:

```
var action = form.data("baseurl") + $(this).val();
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/XQztJ/)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('select[name="producttype"]').change(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.closest('form').attr('action', '/my-url/' + $this.val())
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
var producttype = document.getElementsByName("producttype")[0];
producttype.onchange = function() {
    var form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
    form.action = "/my-url/{{design.id}}/" + this.value;
}
```