# form action not changing on jquery post

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I am trying to change the action of a form after a post.  With this:

```
 $.post(url,data,function(result){
        $( ".page-added" ).append(result);
        $("#edit-form").attr("action", "/edit-settings/");

     })
    return false
  });
```

The result contains the form which has a default action="".

After this jquery, the action does not change.  Is there something I am doing wrong?  I pulled the changed from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925614/jquery-change-form-action-based-on-selection)

I also tried clearing the form first:

```
      $("#edit-form").removeAttr("action").attr("action", "/edit-settings/");
```

The form returned from the result looks like this:

```
<div>
    <form id="edit-form" method="post" action="">{% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset></fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: are you getting any errors??

Comment: @Atma Can we see the form HTML?

Comment: i added the form html

Comment: What's that `}) return false` doing in your code?

Comment: Atma, I just fixed my answer. Try replacing the whole $.post with the one I specified below in my answer. Let me know if it works in the comments. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$.post(url,data,function(result){
    $("#edit-form",$(result)).attr("action", "/edit-settings/");
    $(".page-added").append($(result));
});
```

Comment: @Atma In my answer the form is edited before being appended, just do whatever you have to do before calling `.append()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see what happens...

```
 $.post(url,data,function(result) {
     }).done(function(result) {
        alert('We got back an acceptable result and processing!');
        $( ".page-added" ).append(result);
        $("#edit-form").attr("action", "/edit-settings/");
     }).fail(function() {
        alert('We got back a bad result and failed!');
     }).always(function() {
        alert('We're done with the AJAX routine!');
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

### Yes, but you forgot one thing!

---

Working example of form action change:
http://jsfiddle.net/NetworkNerd/QZeWn/1/

```
$.post(url,data,function(result){
    $(".page-added").append(this);
    $("#edit-form").attr("action", "/edit-settings/index.php");
 });
});
```

Try the code above, it should correctly modify the `action` attribute without any interruption. By the way, make sure the POST is working too.

Comment: @Atma Change the order of the lines. I have a working example I'll show you in the edit i'm about to make.