# how to do make an if statement based on form elements (this is a little hard to explain)

Tags: php, forms, validation, redirect

The code below states my problem, I wanted the user to be redirected to another page when the gender was set to male and the option was set to child. *thank you*

```
<?php
$gender = $age = "";
$age = $_POST['age'];

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST")
{
if (empty($_POST['gender']))
  {
  $gendererr = "Please fill out your gender...";
  }


if ($age == "SELECT")
  {
  $ageerr = "Please select if you are a child or an adult...";
  }

if ($age === $_POST['child'] && $gender === $_POST['male'])
  {
  header('Location: childfather.html');
  }
}
?>
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
<div class="forms-background">
<span class="error"><?php echo $ageerr;?></span>
<br>
<select name="age">
<option name="option">SELECT</option>
<option name="child">Child</option>
<option name="adult">Adult</option>
</select>
<br>
<span class="error"><?php echo $gendererr;?></span><br>
<label>Male</label>
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male"><br>
<label>Female</label>
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female"><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit" class="submit">
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: The first two lines should be fixed. `$gender = $_POST['gender'];`

Comment: options should have values, not name.

Comment: This may be an idea for you to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925614/jquery-change-form-action-based-on-selection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
if ($_POST['age']=='child' && $_POST['gender']=='male'){
   header('Location: childfather.html');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you have to compare the Post variable with a value :

first two line :

```
$age = $_POST['age'];
$gender= $_POST['gender'];
```

And your condition :

```
  if ($age == "child" && $gender == "male")
  {
       header('Location: childfather.html');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$gender = $_POST['gender'];

if ($age == "child" && $gender == "male")
{
 header('Location:childfather.html');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to define the $_POST['gender']

add (on line 3)

```
$gender= $_POST['gender'];
```

then change the operator to == in your condition to be

```
  if ($age == "child" && $gender == "male")
  {
       header('Location: childfather.html');
  }
```