# On a click of one check box new check box has to open in a same page

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp

Hi i want to make design where when i select a one checkbox.
here is a small html code which i write

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="demo3.jsp">
         Networking: <br><input type="checkbox" name="name" value="network" />network<br>
           <input type="checkbox" name="name" value="server" />server<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="name" value="internet" />int<br>
           <input type="submit" value="go">  
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

here there are 3 check box. i want to make ui like when i select one checkbox name "network" the check box name server appear, when i select check box name server checkbox Internet appear.

Comment: Look at this link, I think is the thing you want to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925614/javascript-change-form-action-based-on-selection

Comment: what do you mean by appears? Do you want to check server checkbox when network checkbox is checked or vice-versa? or its related to visibility of the check boxes?

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="network" name="name" value="network" onClick="revealServer();" />network<br>
<div id="serverBox" style="display:none;">
    <input type="checkbox" id="server" name="name" value="server" onClick="revealInternet();" />server<br>
</div>
<div id="internetBox" style="display:none;">
    <input id="internet" type="checkbox" name="name" value="internet" />int<br>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function revealServer() {
        var network = document.getElementById('network');
        var serverBox = document.getElementById('serverBox');
        if(network.checked == true) {
            serverBox.style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById('server').checked = false;
            document.getElementById('internet').checked = false;
        } else {
            serverBox.style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('internetBox').style.display = "none";
        }
    }

    function revealInternet() {
        var server = document.getElementById('server');
        var internetBox = document.getElementById('internetBox');
        if(server.checked == true) {
            internetBox.style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById('internet').checked = false;
        } else {
            internetBox.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Sorry for all the `getElementById` calls, you could probably do this in a cleaner way with JQuery and `getElementByTagName` and similar methods aren't universally supported.

This will also clear the state of the checkboxes when you collapse the tree each time.

Comment: thank you very much man it means a lot for my college project..:)

Comment: hey @Gorb will you give me this code for jquey