# Change the form action attribute taken from values in two selects

Tags: jquery, forms

I've found a similar question here: [javascript - change form action based on selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925614/javascript-change-form-action-based-on-selection)

But my problem is slightly different. I have two selects:

```
 <form id="CarSearch" action="" method="post">
 <select name="style" id="Style">
 <option value="" selected>Any Style</option>
 <option value="style/sports-1">Sports</option>
 <option value="style/wagon-3">Wagon</option>
 <option value="style/suv-6">SUV</option>
 </select>

 <select name="make" id="Make">
 <option value="" selected>Any Make</option>
 <option value="make/porsche-3">Porsche</option>
 <option value="make/ford-6">Ford</option>
 <option value="make/volvo-7">Volvo</option>
 </select>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

I want to build the form action attribute based on the values in both selects. So here are the situations:

1. If both the Style and Make are set to "Any" and hence have no values; the form **action should be blank**.
2. If a Style is specified, but Make isn't; the form action should be **just the value from Style** e.g. `action="style/sports-1"`
3. If a Make is specified, but Style isn't; the form action should be **just the value from Make** e.g. `action="make/volvo-7"`
4. If both a Style and Make are specified; the form action should be a **concatenation of the values** from Style and Make e.g. `action="/style/sports-1/make/volvo-7"`

The defaults for both selects is always "Any". I could try to create two variables in jQuery for each select and set their values whenever either select changes. But its the concatenation part that's confusing me.

I have created a JSFiddle here to get me started **http://jsfiddle.net/L91rb9f9/3/**

I'm ending with two slashes when a Style isn't specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
$("#CarSearch").submit(function () {
    var style = $("#Style").val();
    var make = $("#Make").val();

    if (style == "" && make == ""){
        $('form').get(0).setAttribute('action', '');
    }
    else if (style != "" && make != "")  {
        $('form').get(0).setAttribute('action', style + "/" + make);
    }
    else {
        $('form').get(0).setAttribute('action', style + make);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
function updateForm(){
    var formelem=$('#CarSearch');
    var styleelem=$('#Style');
    var makeelem=$('#Make');

    var action='/';
    action+=styleelem.val();
    if (action.length>1)action+='/';
    action+=makeelem.val();
    formelem.attr('action',action');
}
</script>
<form id="CarSearch" action="" method="post">
 <select onchange="updateForm();" name="style" id="Style">
 <option value="" selected>Any Style</option>


<option value="style/sports-1">Sports</option>
 <option value="style/wagon-3">Wagon</option>
 <option value="style/suv-6">SUV</option>
 </select>

 <select onchange="updateForm();" name="make" id="Make">
 <option value="" selected>Any Make</option>
 <option value="make/porsche-3">Porsche</option>
 <option value="make/ford-6">Ford</option>
 <option value="make/volvo-7">Volvo</option>
 </select>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following jQuery method should satisfy your requirement.

```
$("#CarSearch").click(function (){
    var style = $("#Style").val();
    var make = $("#Make").val();
    var formAction = "";

    if(style != "" && make != ""){
        formAction = "/" + style + "/" + make;
    }else if (style != "" && make == "") {
        formAction = style;
    }else if (style == "" && make != ""){
        formAction = make;
    }else {
       formAction = ""; 
    }
    $("#CarSearch").attr("action", formAction);
    alert('Form Action: ' + $("#CarSearch").attr("action"));
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kq5azprm/1/)

Comment: @volume one: What about this one?

Comment: why on click and not on submit?

Comment: No any difference, I have updated my code as on submission of form.