# multiple actions in a form through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a requirement where i have a form, Input text and a button. On button click i need to call two URL on condition. Is this possible through JavaScript.

For example -

When i click button, if the input text is India the URL should go to http://google.co.in

If the input text is UK the URL should go to http://google.co.uk

What are the ways we can implement this requirement.

```
<form name="inputform" action="somewhere" method="post">
    <input type="text" value=""  />
    <input type="button"  />
</form>
```

Thanks in Advance
Regards

Comment: Please post your code, showing us what you've tried, in your question.

Comment: Show us what you tried, it looks like it shouldnt be harder than a if/else

Comment: Hi I haven;t tried the javascript part..I have only the above form... I want to know how i can achieve it through javascript.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925614/javascript-change-form-action-based-on-selection

Comment: Please have a read here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try something of this sort :

```
  <form name="inputform" action="somewhere" method="post">
        <input type="text" value=""  id="t"/>
         <input type="button" onclick="chkform()" />
 </form>

     <script type="text/javascript">
function chkform(){
        var x =  document.getElementById("t").value;    
        if(x==="India"){
                window.location="http://www.google.com";        
        }   
        else if(x==="UK"){
                window.location="http://www.google.co.uk";  
       }    
  }     

     </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('form').on('submit', function() {
    var inputVal = $('input[type="text"').val();
    if (inputVal === "India") {
        window.location.replace("http://google.co.in");
    } else if (inputVal === "UK") {
        window.location.replace("http://google.co.uk");
    }
});
```

It would help a lot if these HTML elements were given `class` or `ID` attributes to identify them further but this code is a working mashup of JS and jQuery *(as you tagged them both)* of what I think you want.

**N.B:** If you are adding mote conditions, (instead of just *India* and *UK*) it may be worth using a **switch** statement as they look more readable

*This code assumes that your button is the submit button for your form*