# Making a HTML form submit to different places

Tags: javascript, forms, if-statement, action

Hoping someone can help with this. I have a form which has an action attribute. This action attribute enables the user to subscribe to a newsletter when the form is submitted.

What I'm trying to do is only use that action if the user has checked a checkbox giving permission to subscribe to the newsletter. If the checkbox is left unchecked, the form can still be submitted, but will be redirected to a separate URL, disregarding the form's action attribute.

So far this is what I have, I'm not great with javascript so any help would be appreciated.

```
$('document').ready(function () {
 $('#wifi-capture-form').submit(function() {
 var newsletterTrue= $(this).attr("data-newsletter-checked");
 var newsletterFalse= $(this).attr("data-newsletter-unchecked");   
 if ($('input.newsletter-checkbox').is(':checked')) {
  $('#wifi-capture-form').attr('action', newsletterTrue);
 else (
  $('#wifi-capture-form').attr('action', newsletterFalse);
 )    
}
});
```

});

and the form is

```
<form name="wifi-capture-form" id="wifi-capture-form" action="" method="post" class="f24form wifi-capture-form" data-newsletter-checked="https://email.com/t/r/s/dkhywr/" data-newsletter-unchecked="https:www.domain.com/wifi-confirm">

    <label for="fieldName">Name</label><br />
    <input id="fieldName" name="cm-name" class="form-control" type="text" />
    <label for="fieldEmail">Email</label><br/>
    <input id="fieldEmail" class="form-control" name="cm-dkhywr-dkhywr" type="email" required /><br/><br/>

    <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" class="newsletter-checkbox" id="newsletter" value="Subscribe to newsletter"> Subscribe to our newsletter<br/><br/>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

Comment: is f24 something from another library?

Comment: The data-redirect is malformatted, you miss `//` after `https:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by changing the **action attribute** value of the form on submit. Here is the syntax:

```
$("#wifi-capture-form").attr("action", wifiConfirm);
```

So your new code must be like this:

```
 $('#wifi-capture-form').submit(function(e) {
  var wifiConfirm = $(this).attr("data-redirect");

  /* if newslwetter checkbox is not checked, then change form action value*/
  if (!$('input.newsletter-checkbox').is(':checked')) {
    $("#wifi-capture-form").attr("action", wifiConfirm);
  } 

  f24("send", "form", "form.#wifi-capture-form");  
});
```

You can see other examples on [How to change form action based on selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925614/javascript-change-form-action-based-on-selection)

Comment: I see, yes that seems a much better solution. Would this mean I would leave a blank action attribute in the form. eg. action=""

Comment: No, keep html as is. this code just changes the action attribute when the checkbox is not checked, otherwise, the form submits to its original location which is already set in the html

Comment: That may well have done it....thank you very much for your help...much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery you can assign a [click](https://api.jquery.com/click/) event to the checkbox that would dynamically change the action URL in case the checkbox is checked/unchecked.

Comment: Probably the best solution to this kind of problem.